# Increase font size of Cycle2 overlay

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I am trying to increase the size of the overlay in cycle2. However I only want to increase the title and not the description.

Is it possible to target just the data-cycle-title and can this be doen using just css?

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-swipe=true data-cycle-swipe-fx=scrollHorz data-cycle-speed="200" data-cycle-auto-height="1" data-cycle-loader="wait">
    <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
    <div class="cycle-next"></div>
    <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>
    <img src="theme/content/large.jpg" data-cycle-title="NEW CAR COMING SOON" data-cycle-desc="Pre Order now for £1000 off">
</div>
```

Comment: You can't set CSS on the attributes of an element. However, if you check the DOM inspector it's likely this library is creating some elements dynamically. You can then use CSS to target those.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Your right, its creating seperate divs for the title and description. Shame its not giving the divs and id or class. I think i will need to use first-child etc...

Answer (score 0):

Found that it was creating separate divs for each bit so I used this css, replacing the n with the number of the div.

```
.cycle-overlay > div:nth-of-type(n)
```